# Is it possible to operate rfid, ble and sd card module at the same time?

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, esp32, sd-card, rfid, freertos

Can rfid, sd card and ble be used at the same time?
I have 3 different folders in the SD card module and my files in these folders. With Ble, I get data from each folder with a file name (data1.txt, data2.txt, data3.txt). Then, I want to access the data in that file, whichever of the 3 different tags was read with RFID (tag1 = folder1).

While RFID and BLE are running in core 1, I need to get the data in the SD card from core 0. But I can't access the SD card. I'm kind of new to this stuff. My modules work when I use them individually or in pairs. There is no problem with the modules or connections. I might have made a stupid mistake. I'm open to any help. Thanks.. I shared my code below.

```
#include <MFRC522.h> // for the RFID
#include <SPI.h> // for the RFID and SD card module
#include <SD.h> // for the SD card
#include "FS.h"
#include "Arduino.h"
#include "Audio.h"

#include <BLEServer.h>
#include <BLEUtils.h>
#include <BLEDevice.h>
#define SERVICE_UUID        "4fafc201-1fb5-459e-8fcc-c5c9c331914b"
#define CHARACTERISTIC_UUID "beb5483e-36e1-4688-b7f5-ea07361b26a8"



// define pins for RFID
#define CS_RFID 21
#define RST_RFID 22
// define select pin for SD card module
#define CS_SD 5 
//#define SPI_MOSI      23
//#define SPI_MISO      19
//#define SPI_SCK       18

#define I2S_DOUT      25
#define I2S_BCLK      27 
#define I2S_LRC       26

// Instance of the class for RFID
MFRC522 rfid(CS_RFID, RST_RFID); 

// Variable to hold the tag's UID
String uidString;
String file1=,file2=,file3;
int x=0,y=0,z=0,EndOfFile=0;

Audio audio;
// Create a file to store the data
File myFile;

TaskHandle_t Task1;


 //---- Split Files Path ----
void SplitFilesPath(String file_path){
  ...
}

class MyCallbacks: public BLECharacteristicCallbacks {
  std::string RxFile = "";
    void onWrite(BLECharacteristic *pCharacteristic)
    {
      std::string rxValue = pCharacteristic->getValue() ;
      Serial.print("rxValue : ");
      Serial.println(rxValue.c_str());
      if (rxValue.length() > 0) 
      {
        //RxFile += rxValue;
        for (int i=0;i<rxValue.length();i++)
        {
          RxFile += rxValue[i];
        }
        if (rxValue.length()<20)
        {
          Serial.print("RxFile : ");
          Serial.print(RxFile.c_str());
          SplitFilesPath(RxFile.c_str());
          RxFile = "";
        }
      }
    }
};

void setup() {
  // Init Serial port
  pinMode(CS_SD, OUTPUT);
  Serial.begin(115200);

  // Init SPI bus
  SPI.begin();
  // Init MFRC522 
  rfid.PCD_Init(); 
  SD.begin(CS_SD);

  audio.setPinout(I2S_BCLK, I2S_LRC, I2S_DOUT);
  audio.setVolume(10); // 0...21
  myFile = SD.open("/");
  printDirectory(myFile, 0);

  //create a task that will be executed in the Task1code() function, with priority 1 and executed on core 0
  xTaskCreatePinnedToCore(
                    Task1code,   // Task function. 
                    "Task1",     // name of task. 
                    4096,        // Stack size of task
                    NULL,        // parameter of the task 
                    0,           // priority of the task 
                    &Task1,      // Task handle to keep track of created task
                    0);          // pin task to core 0 
}

void printDirectory(File dir, int numTabs) {
  ...
}

//Task1code: Read RFID and Start BLE
void Task1code( void * pvParameters ){
  Serial.println("Ble Connected....");
  BLEDevice::init("HzYusuf");
  BLEServer *pServer = BLEDevice::createServer();

  BLEService *pService = pServer->createService(SERVICE_UUID);

  BLECharacteristic *pCharacteristic = pService->createCharacteristic(
                                         CHARACTERISTIC_UUID,
                                         BLECharacteristic::PROPERTY_READ |
                                         BLECharacteristic::PROPERTY_WRITE
                                       );

  pCharacteristic->setCallbacks(new MyCallbacks());

  pCharacteristic->setValue("Anasinun sutiylan adam olmayana sigir ne etsun");
  pService->start();

  BLEAdvertising *pAdvertising = pServer->getAdvertising();
  pAdvertising->start();

  for(;;){
    if(rfid.PICC_IsNewCardPresent()){
      rfid.PICC_ReadCardSerial();
      uidString = String(rfid.uid.uidByte[0]) + " " + String(rfid.uid.uidByte[1]) + " " + 
      String(rfid.uid.uidByte[2]) + " " + String(rfid.uid.uidByte[3]);
      Serial.println(uidString);
    }
    else{
      uidString = "";
    }
    //vTaskDelay(3 / portTICK_PERIOD_MS);
  }
}



void loop() {
  ...
}
```